# GUI designer to place images within a figure?

Tags: graphics

The latex concept is to script it. Nevertheless, similar to creating powerpoint slides or using QT form designer, for the task of placing images inside a figure, I am more comfortable with a graphical tool. So far, I used lyx for that, but it's not that great for this task, and I was wondering if there's something better?

On the subject, someone introduced me today to hbox, vbox, mbox, vss, hfill, and showed me a hack of vbox to 0pt {...vss} to place images in arbitrary locations (on top of each other) if I wanted to. So maybe I should try to get on top of these things as well.

Comment: There is a much better abstraction for placing things at arbitrary location using [picture mode](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Picture_environment) and a zero-size picture.

Comment: As far as GUI editors for figure placement go, I only know of [Bakoma TeX](http://bakoma-tex.com/) and [Scientific Workplace](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/swp.html~mainFrame) (both commercial).

Answer (score 3):

Putting pictures or other stuff at arbitrary positions is a quite common thing. It can be done i LaTeX in some different ways depending on what you want. Using boxes, spaces and glues, as is hinted in the queastion is one way, but I prefer some other ways.

As commented by Henri Manke it can be made using a zero size picture environment. In those cases I usually make a command `\MyTxt` as below. The name comes from that it can conveniently be used to put text wherever you like, as long as you have a fix point to start the positioning. Here I chose to use it to put a small picture on top a bigger inside a `figure` environment, but it can be used anywhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\MyTxt[3][c]{%
  \put(#2){\makebox(0,0)[#1]{#3}}}
\unitlength=1mm
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \newline
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \MyTxt[lb]{10,40}{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-b}}
  \end{picture}
  \caption{Test of placing something somewhere}
  \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make it easier to find the coordinates where to put the picture it is also nice with a grid. For that `graphpap` can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\MyTxt[3][c]{%
  \put(#2){\makebox(0,0)[#1]{#3}}}
\unitlength=1mm
\usepackage{graphpap}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\greengrid[2]{%
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{green}{\graphpaper(#1)(#2)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \newline
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \greengrid{-40,0}{80,70}
    \MyTxt[lb]{10,40}{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-b}}
  \end{picture}
  \caption{Test of placing something somewhere}
  \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is to use `tikz` where the same thing is even easier

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (6,3){\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test of placing something somewhere}
  \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also here you can include a grid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \draw[green](0,0) grid (8,7);
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (6,3){\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test of placing something somewhere}
  \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the question is really about putting something somewhere on the page, without disturbing the other content, the methods above can also be used. A picture with zero size can always be used. But there is also an option to use a zero size `tikzpicture` by giving the option `overlay`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (3,3){\includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, if I want to put something at a specific location on the page, the `tikz` coorinates can be started with help och `current page` (remember to compile twice). Here `current page.south west` is the lower left corner of the paper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at ($(current page.south west)+(10,20)$){\includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even though I asked about a GUI designer and not necessarily for arbitrary placement, I find you answer useful; thanks.